# Excel-VBA ListBox Item to String function

Tags: excel, vba

I have a Userform which allows user to transfer item from `ListBox1` to `ListBox2`.

**The items in `ListBox2` are supposed to be filenames of excel files which are to be imported.**

I have an overall idea of how this can operate but I am stuck with the problem that I cannot open the file with the item name in `ListBox2`.

My question is, is it possible to "convert" the item name in a `Listbox` to a string so it can be used as the filename for file opening?

I tried to use the MsgBox to test if the `Listbox2(i) / ListBox2.Name(i) / ListBox2.List(i)` argument returns any values but unfortunately it doesn't. It always shows blank.

```
'This is the part where I try to open the files indicated in ListBox2
Dim directory = "my directory is here"

For i = 0 To ListBox2.ListCount - 1

        Application.Workbooks.Open Filename:= directory & "\" & "FinalExcel.xlsx" 'This one is for testing to open file and it works.
        Application.Workbooks.Open Filename:= directory & "\" & ListBox2(i)

Next
```

Comment: You need to use `ListBox2.List(i)` instead of  `ListBox2(i)`

Comment: @TimStack: It works,  thanks! Funny thing is I tried the ```ListBox2.List(i)``` a moment ago and it returned error.  Somehow it worked this time.

Comment: What is the listcount of the listbox?

Comment: @lithiumtin probably had to do with an incorrect index value. Glad it works now!

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, proper way to refer to `ListBox` items in an array-like fashion is via the `ListBox.List(i)` route.

Also a good practice would be to to check first whether the `ListBox` is empty, because attempting to open an empty file (because of non-existent `ListBox` field) will result in an **error!**

```
If Not ListBox2.ListCount = 0 Then
  For i = 0 To ListBox2.ListCount - 1
     Application.Workbooks.Open Filename:= directory & "\" & ListBox2.List(i)
  Next i
End If
```